# how to force reload of react-recaptcha on state change (language update)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I want to reload reCaptcha widget on my state change, when I get new current_lang.

I used componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.recaptchaInstance) {
    this.recaptchaInstance.reset();
  }
}
```

which looks like it re-render component, but language stays the same?

this is my component

```
<Recaptcha
  ref={e => (this.recaptchaInstance = e)}
  sitekey="using_it_just_didnt_copy_it_here"
  size="normal"
  render="explicit"
  hl={language.current_lang}
  onloadCallback={this.onloadRecaptcha}
/>
```

Can someone please point me in right direction? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure `language.current_lang` is actually different when you do the reset?

Comment: @Chris yes I am, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need to re-mount `Recaptcha` rather than just re-rendering it. You should use the `key` prop to force a re-mount:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.key = 0;
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.recaptchaInstance) {
    this.key++; 
  }
}
```

```
<Recaptcha
  key={this.key}
  ref={e => (this.recaptchaInstance = e)}
  sitekey="using_it_just_didnt_copy_it_here"
  size="normal"
  render="explicit"
  hl={language.current_lang}
  onloadCallback={this.onloadRecaptcha}
/>
```

Comment: This actually works! Will mark it as Answer as soon as system allow, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Comment: This will make component state unpredictable and undebuggable. Acting in componentDidUpdate without affecting state and not being triggered by state changes will make you to lose the half of the power of Redux.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Redux? There is no mention of this in OP?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I see now, it was mentioned in a comment in your answer... It is hard to suggest a solid answer with limited code included. I agree that this is smelly, but the idea I am trying to convey is that by using a new `key` you can force a re-mount. The rest are implementation details that we don't know.

Comment: React allows a large sets of solutions to be applied. Unfortunately where you have 100 solutions, 95 are considered anti-patterns so starting with a pattern with as few drawbacks as possible will save your life. A single antipattern is not dangerous but when you begin to build an antipattern on the top of other antipattern your life could turn in a hell in no time.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I agree. It is easy to see the antipattern here, but not the full solution. OP said that the language prop actually changes, but this doesnt change the language. In other words, to my understanding, this Captcha component (which is a library) cant change language through re-render, but only with re-mount.

Comment: @Chris I agree with you too. Sometimes simple patterns to be applied need more code (at least a working snippet) to be examined.

Comment: Yes, I don't change language.current_lang in this component, but using reducer which is triggered in header component when lang is changed, hope this is correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

componentDidUpdate used in this way will make the state of the application inconsistent and/or less predictable.
I suggest that hl={language.current_lang} should be hl={state.current_lang}. Updating the state with a new language through setState() will make the view to render again with new values (updated language) and will keep state consistent, predictable and easily debbugable through (I.E.) react dev tools.

Comment: Hi, I actually get lang from redux state, so its this.props.language.current_lang

Comment: this is the same as local state, change the redux state through saga->reducer or directly in the reducer. The value of redux debugger make it double important to keep it consistent. When your app will grow enough you'll thanx yourself for taking care of such aspects of state consistency and predictability :)